# How to lock/unlock ACL of a windows process?

Tags: windows, process

I know that you can modify the ACL of a process to forbid termination. But if I do so in a program, I'm still able to "reset" these rights for example with the Process Explorer.

But for the Anti Virus Software that I use, this is not possible and I wonder why?

Even with the SYSTEM account I cannot read or write the "process permissions".

Any ideas how this can be forbidden and how I can get back the right to terminate such a program?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Try SuperUser.

Comment: This is off-topic. Try [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) as suggested by @RaymondChen

Comment: AV software does this by injecting parts of itself into the kernel.

Comment: @RaymondChen to be more clear: i want to know how the program did this and implement the same

Comment: Don't do it yourself. That will make your app look like malware.

Comment: @HarryJohnston i thought the only way to do this would be to alter the SSDT and reroute NtTerminateProcess - but this is not done; also no DLL-injection to reroute the user-space functions - do you have an idea how else this could be done?

Comment: @RaymondChen i'm aware of that - but how do they do it? (but it's kind of funny that you say that and the program that does this trick is an ANTI virus/malware program)

Comment: Naturally they know to ignore themselves.

Comment: There are presumably any number of ways this could be done, too many to list.  I think there are some callback functions you can register for a start.  If I remember correctly, there's also an entire API dedicated specifically for anti-virus software to use, so they don't have to do nasty things like hooking the SSDT.  But I don't recall the details offhand.